# ANOVA normality assumption for which variables?

Tags: anova, normal-distribution, normality-assumption

When I want to conduct a repeated measures ANOVA pre and post test scores, which variables need to be tested for normality?

Each the pre and post scores or the difference between them?

I suppose the difference as with the t-test. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RM ANOVA the variables do not need to be normally distributed. However, RM ANOVA does make assumptions about the *conditional* distributions of the dependent variable; this is tested by looking at residuals.

It also makes the assumption of sphericity, which is often unreasonable in repeated measure designs.

Comment: Thank you Peter! In another question I've read that it's quite daunting to check the the normality of residuals. Someone else suggested that normality is not needed with modest sample size.

Comment: There are no perfect ways to check for normality. But with a modest sample size, if anything, the requirement is more necessary (but harder to check)